# Array from interpolated plot in python

Tags: python, arrays, matplotlib, plot, interpolation

I have an array with a grid size of 150x80. I plotted the data and interpolate them. This is my figure:

[image: This is my figure:]

Here is my problem: I would like to do some calculations on the interpolated data, that's why I need to write the image back in an array with more details as the previous. Is it possible?

----- NEW EDIT -----

This is my code. As you can see I interpolate data in the plot, so I don't actually have a callable interpolation, but an image.

```
clip=abs(np.percentile(sint_h, 0.999))
fig, ax = plt.subplots(2,figsize=(10,10))
im0=ax[0].imshow(sint_h,extent=[0,sint_h.shape[1],sint_h.shape[0]*sr,0],interpolation='bilinear',aspect='auto',cmap='RdBu',vmin=-clip,vmax=clip)
im1=ax[1].imshow(specamps_h,extent=[0,specamps_h.shape[1],ufreq_range_h.max(),0],interpolation='bilinear',aspect='auto',cmap='rainbow')
ax[0].set_ylabel('TWT [s]')
ax[1].set_ylabel('FREQUENCY [Hz]')
ax[1].set_y
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible. The interpolation returns a `callable` so you can just call it with your wanted grid:

```
from scipy.interpolate import interp2d
import numpy as np

x = 50
y = 150

a = np.random.uniform(0,10,(y, x))
b = interp2d(np.arange(x), np.arange(y), a)
```

That was just to create some test data. To get what you want you need to evaluate the interpolation `b` on a grid of your choosing:

```
upsample_factor = 2
c = b(np.linspace(0,x,x*upsample), np.linspace(0,y,y*upsample))
```

That creates a grid with 2 times the number of elements that your original array had.

Or you could just define some box around your region of interest and call it with `np.linspace` with the required number of elements.

Comment: Thank you! That's not exactly what I thought, but it is usefull!

Comment: Hi, sorry again!
I'm trying to use your script but something got wrong...
If I use interp2d on my data I got the error "ValueError: x and y must have equal lengths for non rectangular grid"

Comment: just use ``np.arange(sint_h.shape[0])`` and ``np.arange(sint_h.shape[1])`` as arguments for ``interp2d``. But I just got what you wanted ... you wanted the interpolated image from matplotlib for later usage?

Comment: uhm...not exactly... I want to do some calculations on interpolated values...
e.g. I need to find the maximus y value with x value=8.5